# webpack prefetch with react Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, prefetch

I want to add a prefetch for a component in React Router, but currently the component is a Dynamic Import. Adding webpackprefetch= true does not work. Hence want to know what would be the best way to add webpackprefetch= true to React router.

I tried using:

```
const SCHEDULES = () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true / / webpackChunkName: "SchedulesPage" */ "./schedules/Schedules");
```

but that does not create an component.

**Current code:**

```js
<Switch>
    { /* Schedules page */ }
   <Route exact path={ `${match.url}/schedules` } component={ Schedules } />
</Switch>
```

```js
const Schedules = (props: any) => (
    <DynamicRouteImport load={ () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "SchedulesPage" */ /* webpackPrefetch: true */ "./schedules/Schedules") }>
        { (Component: any) => Component === null
        ? <DynamicRouteSpinner />
        : <><GlobalCommandBar /><Component {...props} /></> }
    </DynamicRouteImport>
);
```

Comment: your "current code" seems to be commented out, I'm not sure what we're supposed to make of that

Comment: The formatting was wrong. Corrected it.Hope that makes the code clear

Comment: How are you exporting this Schedules component? Is a named export or default export?

Comment: Its exported as "export default hot(module)(Schedules)"

Comment: Did you get an answer for prefetching the component before the route load?